# Do I need a router even though I have an Windows Server with AD DS?

Tags: networking, active-directory

I am a newbie playing around with basic networking and Active Directory. I have successfully setup Windows Server w/ AD DS. The Windows Server runs DHCP, DNS, etc.

However, for my ISP provided modem/router, I believe I should be setting this to Bridge Mode since the Windows Server would handle the routing. Is this thinking incorrect, and should I be keeping my ISP provided modem/router unbridged with DHCP disabled?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It's not a best practice to multi home a domain controller. For that reason it's better to secure your WAN with a router. The ISP modem is often limited in functionality (vpn function, port forward, etc..), thus I suggest to use another router while having the modem in bridge mode.

Quote from [Multihomed DCs with DNS, RRAS, and/or PPPoE adapters](https://blogs.msmvps.com/acefekay/2009/08/17/multihomed-dcs-with-dns-rras-and-or-pppoe-adapters/)

> A Multihomed DC is a domain controller with more than one NIC and/or
>   IP address, and/or RRAS installed on it (for VPN, routing, dialup,
>   etc), or with a PPPoE adapter from your ISP’s ADSL line. Multihomed
>   DCs wiill cause numerous issues.
>
> The only exception to the rule are
>   SBS servers, but that is a completely different topic which I will not
>   address in this blog, but I can add that even the SBS gurus recommend
>   to single-home it.
>
> It’s highly recommended to single-home all DCs and
>   use a non-DC for multihoming purposes. If it’s the internet gateway,
>   such as using the DC as a NAT device, not only will the multihomed DC
>   cause AD problems, but you’re also exposing the DC directly on the
>   internet. To overcome both of these issues, I recommend disabling the
>   outer NIC and purchasing an inexpensive cable/DSL firewall/router or
>   other type of firewall/NAT device for this purpose. My preference is a
>   Cisco ASA device. There are also less expensive options, such as a
>   Linksys wireless N router for less than USD $150, and there are less
>   expensive models under it. If the hardware device is compromised by an
>   internet attacker remotely, it can’t further compromise the rest of
>   the internal network, nor your DC.  If you have a PPPoE adapter
>   installed (such as the WinPoet software from Verizon for ADSL lines),
>   it will cause the same problems, for after all, they are additional
>   interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

> However, for my ISP provided modem/router, I believe I should be
>   setting this to Bridge Mode since the Windows Server would handle the
>   routing. Is this thinking incorrect, and should I be keeping my ISP
>   provided modem/router unbridged with DHCP disabled?

The Windows server will not handle the routing for your network. You need to continue using your ISP provided modem/router. You can disable the DHCP server function on the router and use the DHCP role on the server to assign ip addressing configuration to the network hosts. Make sure the DHCP server assigns the router ip address as the router for your network hosts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes this is what I have currently done and it has been working so far. I'll also consider getting my own router for routing when I am more familiar with networking.